# How to hide column in columnSelection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-bootgrid

Please refer the below image. i want to set the Column selection for Sender and Receiver. Id should not put in column selection drop-down. How to do this in bootgrid?

## Image for Reference

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got solution for this question in **Bootgrid version 1.3**. I have raised a ticket for this issue to bootgrid supporters, They were added the new functionality in new version, It is called

```
visibleInSelection
```

Default value of this is **true.**

You have to set false for table row.

**GitHub** issue Link : https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid/issues/195

## HTML Table

```
<th data-column-id="Id" data-visible-in-selection="false">Id</th>
```

Thats it.
Now You dont care about hidden the id and all those things.. **Happy coding** guys